# JSONDecodeError: sending java JSONObject with DataOutputStream, python receives through socket but json.loads doesn't work

Tags: python, java, json, sockets

I prepared a JSONObject in java, encoded it in UTF-8 and sent it through a socket to a python server.
Python receives, but using json.loads() fails because somehow the data is not properly configured, hence cannot be converted into a dictionary and handled.

### JAVA

```java
    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
    Socket clientSocket;
    [...]
    clientSocket = new Socket(Server.getOrchestrator(), 5051);
    DataOutputStream outToServer = new DataOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
    obj.put("operation", "provider list");
    outToServer.writeUTF(obj.toString());
```

### PYTHON

```py
    socket = (socket configuration here)
    socket.listen(5)
    client, address = socket.accept()
    threading.Thread(target=self.serve_client, args=(client, address)).start()
```

```
    def serve_client(self, client, address):
      SIZE = 1024
      while True:
         recv_data = client.recv(SIZE).decode('utf-8')
         print(recv_data)
         print(type(recv_data))
         recv_data = json.loads(recv_data) # <-- this breaks
```

##### Output:

```
error JSONDecodeError('Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)',)
```

##### Output before decoding:

```
b'\x00\xld{"operation":"provider list"}'
```

What I tried to do in order to solve:
reading through lots of Q&A here, instead of DataOutputStream I tried

### JAVA

```java
OutputStreamWriter outToServer = new OutputStreamWriter (clientSocket.getOutputStream(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8); // <-- this hangs, looks like python doesn't receive anything because nothing is printed
```

```java
BufferedReader outToServer = new BufferedReader(new OutputStreamWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8)); // <-- same as before, this hangs
```

### PYTHON

Attempt 1

```py
recv_data = client.recv(SIZE) # without decode, are received bytes
recv_data = json.dumps(recv_data) # breaks because this can't handle bytes
recv_data = json.loads(recv_data)
```

Attempt 2

```
recv_data = client.recv(SIZE).decode('utf-8')
recv_data = json.dumps(recv_data) # it works
print(f"String recv_data converted in string: {recv_data}\nRecv_data type {type(recv_data)})
recv_data = json.loads(recv_data) # it doesn't work ->  doesn't return a dictionary, I get another string instead # to be sure I have a JSON-compatible string
print(f"String recv_data converted in dictionary: {recv_data}\nRecv_data type {type(recv_data)})
```

Output referenced to this attempt:

```
{"operation":"provider list"}
<class 'str'>
String recv_data converted in string: "\u0000\u001d{\"operation\":\"provider list\"}"
Recv_data tyoe: <class 'str'>
String recv_data converted in a dictionary: {"operation": "provider list"}
Recv_data type: <class 'str'>
```

The whole codes are very complex (and very, VERY messy). I'm not the one who wrote them (although looks like I'm the one who'll fix them): that's why I omitted some stuff

Comment: It looks like you're getting the length as the first few bytes of the data.  If you strip that off, then you should be able to `loads` the resulting string.  I can't tell whether the length is 2 bytes or 4 bytes.  If you had shown us `print(recv_data)` before doing any decoding, we could advise you.

Comment: @TimRoberts right. Question updated with that output :)

Comment: @TimRoberts  ```recv_data = client.recv(SIZE).decode('utf-8').strip()``` doesn't fix the JSONDecodeError :C but json.loads works

Comment: You need `recv_data = client.recv(SIZE)[2:].decode('utf-8')`.  The first two bytes give you the length of the upcoming string, but are not part of the JSON.  To be more correct, you should read the two bytes, then use THAT value to decide how many bytes to read.  TCP is a streaming protocol; if the client sends two things in a row, you can receive them both together.  That would screw you up.